# Can't access Apache 2.4 server except on localhost

Tags: apache-2.4

I recently installed Apache 2.4 on a Windows Server 2012 machine.

Apache is listening on port 8079 (IIS is installed on that machine too)

It works fine if I access the web server with http://localhost:8079. However I can't access it on other computers on the network. I can't even access it with my own (server's) network ip address (192.168.9.3). Apache doesn't generate any error (403 or something). The connection just times out after a few seconds without talking to Apache.

IIS works fine on port 80, even on the LAN.

Port 8079 seems to be opened.

```
C:\ms4w\Apache\bin>netstat -a -n | find "8079"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8079           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I added a firewall rule to accept incoming connections on port 8079. According to the logs, it is accepting the connection.

Part of my httpd.conf file:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8079
```

....

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

....

```
<Directory "C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Well now I am clueless... Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I didn't realized that we were using DNS on the network. All I had to do (with the provided information) is to access the web server with

```
server1.something.local:8079/
```

instead of

```
192.168.16.3:8079/
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking all these items?

1. Check your web browser proxy settings ? If you use proxies, make sure to set your IP address added under "Do not use proxy settings for these addresses..." section in your web browser.
2. Firewall ? Try Disabling them first.
3. Software protection agents ? Such as Symantec protection agent ?
4. Windows trusted app section, you might want to allow these apps to run on a certain network/ports.

Also always check your event logs for error messages. Also check your Apache error logs for hints.

The trick in general is list out the possibilities of software/feature in OS that could pose problems and then turn on/off them to validate it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is nothing like a good night to think about a problem! I woke up this morning and I realized that the network uses DNS. I had to replace the ip by server1.something.local:8079/

Comment: Cool, glad that you solved the issue. Cheers! :)